# How to hide MULTIPLE sections and show only one section in Elementor with a button (NOT Accordion)?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, elementor

I have multiple sections in Elementor with IDs #section1, #section2, #section3 and so on...
I created buttons and each button functionality should be to show only one section and hide ALL others. I can do that only for 1 section and 1 button with JS, but it seems I am not successful with multiple sections. I need to do that without refreshing the page. Any ideas?

Comment: If you wrote code that working for 1 section you can make it work for all sections trying to write it as function and pass sections IDs to it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if this is what you want but seems to work for me

`enter code here`

```
`enter code here`</div>
`enter code here`<div id="section2">

`enter code here`</div>

`enter code here`<button class="section1">button1</button>
`enter code here`<button class="secss">button2</button>
```

use your own styling

the javascript
`enter code here`"use strict";

`enter code here`const btn1 = document.querySelector(".section1");
`enter code here`const btn2 = document.querySelector(".secss");

`enter code here`const section1 = document.getElementById("section1");
`enter code here`const section2 = document.getElementById("section2");

`enter code here`btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
`enter code here`section1.classList.add("hidden");
`enter code here`});

`enter code here`btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
`enter code here`section1.classList.remove("hidden");
`enter code here`section2.classList.add("hidden");
`enter code here`});